# Why does handwriting change?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, emotion, writing

In New York magazine it is stated:

> [I]t’s strange that your handwriting changes over time; scientifically speaking, there’s no reason it should. At a certain point, you’ve learned all there is to learn about it: You’ve mastered the fine motor skills, you know the right way to grip a pen, you’ve written enough that you no longer need to think about the physical act of forming letters with your hand.

But they continue:

> But still, odds are decent that your handwriting right now looks a little bit different than it did five years ago, and will look different again in five more.

Now **I am wondering if handwriting can also change on a smaller time scale, and specifically with regard to emotional states**. If yes, I would be interested in **what part of the brain controls it**.

Comment: With AliceD's edit the question now falls within the minimum expected, so I have reopened. I notice he dropped personal anecdotes. I would like to point out these are not irrelevant (you can edit them back in), but the important thing to do is do _some_ initial research and relate your anecdotes to them, thus to _some_ degree motivating your question and making it relevant for a broader audience.

Answer (score 3):

The brain is an **interconnected whole**, when we have high activity in one area of the brain other connected parts are affected.

The writting is mostly controlled by the part of the brain that controls movement (lateral and medial precentral, motor cingulate and primary motor cortices, and postcentral gyrus). Research revealed that there is a direct path between amygdala and the parts of the brain that controls movement. Subsequntly writting will be affected when the amygdala is highly active.

> Using diffusion-weighted magnetic resonance imaging and probabilistic
>   tractography on a cohort of 40 participants, we provide evidence of a
>   structural connection between the amygdala and motor-related areas
>   (lateral and medial precentral, motor cingulate and primary motor
>   cortices, and postcentral gyrus) in humans. ... a direct
>   amygdala-motor pathway might provide a mechanism by which the amygdala
>   can influence more complex motor behaviors.

Reference

[Grèzes J., Valabrègue R., Gholipour B., Chevallier C., A direct amygdala-motor pathway for emotional displays to influence action: A diffusion tensor imaging study.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25053375)

Comment: I like your answer +1. Just wished to let you know that the edited question does not clash with your original answer here.

Comment: @AliceD I have tried to change the answer to be more in line with the edited version of the question. I find the question very interesting, I would like to see more answers and comments on this topic. I have voted for reopen.

Answer (score 0):

I can say if you look into the way hand-writing is analyzed you can find that emotions is your answer. This is old, but a few years ago people were televised for being able to read your hand-writing and psychically read your emotions.

To answer one of your questions, i think a less emotional review in business could get you a more consistent handwriting. Maybe a business memo, but you should take notice to the changes. I always do. When i'm sad I see the letters of my writing go downward below the line. When i'm ecstatic i see the writing go upward

Comment: Could you add some sources to your answer, perhaps in the first part?